# PHP MySQL Transactions

Tags: php, mysql

Is there anyway to carry out an SQL transaction in one command? eg

```
mysql_query("
START TRANSACTION;
INSERT INTO table1 ....etc;
INSERT INTO table 2.....;
COMMIT;");
```

Or do you always have to use separate commands? eg

```
mysql_query("START TRANSACTION;");
mysql_query("INSERT INTO etc etc
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can, by using PDO instead of pure mysql statements,

```
$connection = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test', 'user', 'password');
$connection->beginTransaction();
$connection->exec('insert into table1...');
$connection->exec('insert into table2...');
$connection->commit();
```

Of course, this is just a quick example, you should use prepared statements instead and use bind variables for the user input so you won't have to worry that much about sql injections.

Answer (score 0):

With the PHP mysql_query function it has to be separate calls.

Answer (score 0):

MySql supports transactions if you use InnoDb as storage engine. The mysql api doesn't allow multiple statements to be passed to `mysql_query`, but since a transaction is per connection, you can just split it up over multiple calls.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use PDO you can use mysqli's [multi_query](http://pt.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php) commnad